# Remove buttons from PrimeNG PickList in Angular

Tags: angular, primeng, picklist

In the following image, I would like to have only single-item selection buttons and remove the select all buttons (marked by the black bubbles).

[image: picklist screenshot]

I am using [PrimeNG Picklist](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/picklist) to generate the list.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: You can do it by *ngIf in button attribute

Answer (score 6):

This works for me. In October 2021 still no property to hide these buttons.

```
  ::ng-deep .p-picklist-buttons > button:nth-child(2),
  ::ng-deep .p-picklist-buttons > button:nth-child(4) {
      display: none;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

PrimeNg have no option to remove buttons. But we can do it with listbox.

step 1: 
Import ListboxModule in app.module.ts

```
import {ListboxModule} from 'primeng/listbox';
...
imports: [
ListboxModule
...
],
```

Step 2: app.component.html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <p-listbox [options]="users" filter="filter" multiple="true" checkbox="true"
        [style]="{'width':'100%'}" [listStyle]="{'max-height': '200px'}" [metaKeySelection]="false"
        [(ngModel)]="selectedUserList"></p-listbox>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="my-2 ml-3"><i class="pi pi-angle-double-right clickable"
            (click)="moveUserToGroupMember()"></i></div>
        <div class="my-2 ml-3"><i class="pi pi-angle-double-left clickable" 
            (click)="moveGroupToUser()"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <p-listbox [options]="groupUserList" filter="filter" multiple="true" checkbox="true"
        [style]="{'width':'100%'}" [listStyle]="{'max-height': '200px'}" [metaKeySelection]="false"
        [(ngModel)]="selectedGroupUsersList"></p-listbox>
    </div>
</div>
```

Step 3: app.component.ts file with manual functionality of picklist

```
export class AppComponent {
public users = [];
public groupUserList = [];
public selectedUserList:any;
public selectedGroupUsersList:any;
constructor AppComponent(){
this.users = [
    { label: 'Ganesh', value: '3' },
    { label: 'John', value: '1' },
    { label: 'Joshua', value: '2' },


  ];
  this.groupUserList = [
    { label: 'Vetri', value: '5' },
    { label: 'shiva', value: '6' },
  ];
};


  moveUserToGroupMember() {
    this.users.forEach((elem, index) => {
      this.selectedUserList.forEach((selUser, indexes) => {
        if (selUser === elem.value) {
          this.groupUserList.push(elem);
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.removeByAttr(this.users, 'value', selUser);
          }, 500);
        }
      });
    });
  }
  moveGroupToUser() {
    this.groupUserList.forEach((elem, index) => {
      this.selectedGroupUsersList.forEach((selUser, indexes) => {
        if (selUser === elem.value) {
          this.users.unshift(elem);
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.removeByAttr(this.groupUserList, 'value', selUser);
          }, 500);
        }
      });
    });
  }

  removeByAttr = (arr, attr, value) => {
    let i = arr.length;
    while (i--) {
      if (arr[i]
        && arr[i].hasOwnProperty(attr)
        && (this.users.length > 0 && arr[i][attr] === value)) {

        arr.splice(i, 1);

      }
    }
    return arr;
  }

}
```

You can get selected Users from selectedUserList:any and selectedGroupUserList:any. That’s it now you can able to move users from one list to another list.

For More Reference :

[helperscript.com](https://helperscript.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=393&action=edit)

[Demo image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xi0hq.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the `p-picklist` [source](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/picklist/picklist.ts#L51), you could set the CSS display property of these buttons to `none`. But to truly remove them from the implementation, there is no out-of-the-box solution. You need to extend it and remove it yourself.

Try the following CSS

```css
button[icon="pi-angle-double-right"],
button[icon="pi-angle-double-left"] {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this below code to disable the button or use similar js dom manipulation to hide the button.

```js
const targetCtrl = document.getElementsByClassName("p-picklist-target-controls")[0].parentNode;  

const targetTransferCtrl = targetCtrl.childNodes[3];
targetTransferCtrl.childNodes[0]['disabled'] = true;
targetTransferCtrl.childNodes[1]['disabled'] = true;
targetTransferCtrl.childNodes[2]['disabled'] = true;
targetTransferCtrl.childNodes[3]['disabled'] = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work in removing the for All Source and Target button.

```
::ng-deep button[icon="pi pi-angle-double-right"],
::ng-deep button[icon="pi pi-angle-double-left"] {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
setTimeout(() => {
      let doubleRight = document.getElementsByClassName("pi-angle-double-right");
      let doubleLeft = document.getElementsByClassName("pi-angle-double-left");
      doubleRight.item(0).parentElement.style.display="none"
      doubleLeft.item(0).parentElement.style.display="none"
}, 100);
```

:)